# How to store your login credentials to avoid write them again

Tags: c#, .net, angular, security

What I want to do is something common in web pages. You write your email and password and then if you close the page and go back in, you won't have to write them again.

I am using Angular in FrontEnd and .NET 6 in Backend

My first thought is to store your email and password in local storage and when the user enters the page again, the app will read the variables in local storage and try to log in. Looking at other pages, it seems that they do not store this data, which made me think that this was not the correct option.

The second thing I thought of was to store the email and password in .NET, but I don't know if this will work with many clients, I also don't know how to store these credentials permanently.

I hope someone can tell me how to do this in a safe way, at least safer than these options.

Comment: ***DO NOT STORE USERNAMES AND PASSWORDS***, it really doesn't matter how or where. Use cookies and server side session management.

Comment: Used an authentication cookie : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/cookie?force_isolation=true&view=aspnetcore-6.0

Comment: @Daevin I'm pretty sure OP really asks about how autocomplete works having misguided idea that web sites/pages themselves store passwords... Following search  https://www.bing.com/search?q=how+browsers+detect+password+fields+from+autocomplete may help OP to clarify what they are looking for.